# Draft item security Any user who can read items but not anonymous

Tags: security, anonymous-authentication, access, item, draft

I have a list which has the following settings:

- Content Approval: Enabled
- Versioning: Enabled (Major and Minor)
- Draft Item Security: **Any user who can read items**

This list resides in an anonymous access enabled publishing site.

I want to show last approved version of list items to anonymous users, but draft version to all authenticated users (they may have only read permission, or contribute, or full control).

But whenever I add a list item, anonymous users can be able to see newly created item although it is draft.